# If a black hole cannot have a diameter smaller than Planck length (a finite and non-zero length), then how can we call it a singularity?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, singularities

As title. If a black hole has a minimum finite diameter, than it should not mathematically be a singularity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General Relativity is a classical theory, not a quantum theory. There is nothing in General Relativity that makes a black hole have a minimum radius for its event horizon. It can be arbitrarily small.

Furthermore, the event horizon of the hole, which is at $r=2GM/c^2$ for a hole with no angular momentum and no charge, is not the singularity. The singularity is inside the event horizon at $r=0$. The event horizon and the singularity are two completely different things.

Some (maybe most?) physicists think that, when we have a correct theory of quantum gravity, there will be a minimum radius for the event horizon, and no singularity inside.

Comment: Is that the very last paragraph means little will change at the EH but a totally new description of the inside? Or this would result in smaller radius of EH as is mass - with no singularity - is less concentrated? In other words, at a given EH radius, would be M the same? Or we simply don't know what would be the outcome beside singularity removal?

Comment: It will depend on the theory. For example, here are two quite different ideas, one from string theory and one from loop quantum gravity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzball_(string_theory) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_star